# Calling WebService with Service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, service-reference

I am trying to call a web service that I have made. I have published it to a website, and added it to my solution as a Service Reference. All the calls are there, all the classes are there too. But when I try to call it, I get an invalid class.

**Exception**

> Cannot convert from 'GoS.GoSubmitWS.consent' to 'GoS.GoS.GoGetWS.consent'

**Code**

```
GoSubmitWS.consent consent = Database.DBConsent.GetConsentInfo(mjE.mj_message);

if (consent == null)
    return;

GoSubmitWS.GoSubmit_WebServiceClient wsClient = new GoSubmitWS.GoSubmit_WebServiceClient();

wsClient.ConsentInformation(Settings.Entity, mjE.mj_message, consent);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: looks like conflict between classes  with same name in two namespaces. You have GoS.GoSubmitWS added as a reference to your consuming application and consent class also exists in your web service ?

Comment: I may have solved the issue by going through the generated service reference file and removing the namespace references in GoS.GoSubmitWS.consent went to GoSubmitWS.consent. Still needs testing though. Will post if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by going through the generated service reference file and removing the namespace references in GoS.GoSubmitWS.consent went to GoSubmitWS.consent.